# How to uninstall PHP 5.6.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, uninstallation

I've just finished installing PHP 7 per [these instructions](https://robotsystematic.com/compile-php7-rc-01-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid)

How do I uninstall PHP 5.6.4?  This version of PHP was installed when I updated to Ubuntu 15.04.

The result of **php-v** is

```
PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:29:28) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```